Connecting to server through ssh in R
Does anyone have a way to ssh connect to a server and then set that as my working directory in R Studio? So far I've been able to run:
library("ssh")
session <- ssh_connect("server@name")

Then I try to access specific files on the server and it says that the files and directories can't be found. When I getwd() it looks like I'm still on my personal desktop. Am I missing a step?
Have already tried:
setwd(session)
setwd(ssh_connect("server@name")
setwd("ssh://server@name")


What you are doing is create an object in R that represents your SSH session. To perform things via SSH you will need to interact with that object. Neither setwd() nor RStudio know about this session. What you want is simply not possible. You’d have to rewrite both R and RStudio to be able to use SSH connections transparently; using a package in the way you did won’t work. — That said, I think for your purposes you might be interested in RStudio Cloud, which can run run directly on the server, and to which you connect via your browser.

Some XY-problem vibes here . With {ssh} R package, you can either copy remote files to your local system (or from local to remote)  and execute something remotely.  If you want to mount remote file system over ssh,  it should be handled outside of R,  there's sshfs  for that.  You have not provided details about your local system, but there's also sshfs-win, a port for Windows.

On Linux you could mount that server on say /home/<you>/mnt/ using e.g. sshfs and then setwd('/home/<you>/mnt/')`.

Thank you all for the help! Sounds like I'll have to do a workaround and maybe get the proper software installed on the server so that I can just run the R script on there. Thanks!
